# sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 0, and there are 2 supplied

Tags: sqlite

I am crawling a site for certain details then from there i wanna save them in a database, below is the function to the above task:

```
def store(title, body):
    conn = sqlite3.connect('test2.db')
    print("Connection established")
    conn.execute("insert into crawled (title, body) values (\"%s\", \"%s\");",(title, body))
    conn.commit()
    print("Records Created Successfully")
    conn.close()
```

but i keep getting this error:

```
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 0, and there are 2 supplied
```

I have gone through all of the available solutions in **Stack** but none are solving my problem, can please, please someone out there show me my error.

Comment: The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html) explains how to use parameters.

Comment: Could it be a syntax problem? have you tried using the "?" symbol instead of "%s" conn.execute("insert into crawled (title, body) values (?,?);",(title, body))

Comment: I have tried everything, even the "?" symbol, its still not working

Answer (score 6):

The problem seems to stem from a small syntax error.

For the execute command use:

```
conn.execute("insert into crawled (title, body) values (\"%s\", \"%s\");" %(title, body))
```

Note the `%` at the start of `%(title, body)` and the lack of a comma before it.

Or:

```
conn.execute("insert into crawled (title, body) values (?, ?);",(title, body))
```

Note the comma before the brackets and the lack of quotation marks around the `?`.

The [sqlite3 documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html) should have all the information needed. Be aware that it mentions that it's better to use option two, to avoid potential SQL injection attacks.

Comment: Could the down-voter please enlighten me as to what has displeased them?